# В таблице генерируется в два раза больше строк чем нужно

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Здравствуйте. Есть функция, которая вставляет в таблицу строки и ячейки, но она вставляет всегда в два-три раза больше строк и ячеек чем нужно. Как исправить ту ситуацию?

Вот как выглядит код пустой таблицы:

```
<table id="myTable" class=""></table>
```

Вот функция, которая генерирует строки и ячейки:

```
function makeTable(){

  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');

  for (var cols = 0; cols < 2; cols++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tr);

     for (var rows = 0; rows < 2; rows++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
     }
  }
      return table;
}
```

```js
function makeTable() {

  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');

  for (var cols = 0; cols < 2; cols++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tr);

    for (var rows = 0; rows < 2; rows++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }
  return table;
}
makeTable();
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" class=""></table>
```

Comment: А сколько нужно? Этим кодом Вы добавляете две строки с двумя столбцами в каждой. Что не так?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, да. В теории должно так и получится. Две строки с двумя столбцами. Но на практике у меня генерируется 8 строк с двумя столбцами. Я вот не могу понять почему так происходит. Из-за этого очень виснет скрипт.

Comment: Значит у Вас эта функция вызывается 4 раза. Добавьте в функцию первой строкой `console.log('MyFunc')` и смотрите

Comment: Сниппет с твоим кодом не воспроизводит проблему. Ищи ее в своем оставшемся коде

Comment: "Хочешь, бабка, угадаю ...?" Твардовский "Василий Теркин" - Вы добавляете обработчики событий, вызывающие `makeTable`, больше чем один раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сама функция работает ожидаемо – вставляет две строки с двумя колонками **за один вызов**, поэтому ошибка кроется не в ней, а в вызывающем её коде. То есть **где-то происходят лишние вызовы этой функции**.

Comment: Больше на комментарий смахивание, но никак не на ответ

Comment: @Cheg, какой тут ещё может быть ответ? Автор делает неверное предположение о том, что сама функция работает неверно. Но это не так. Функция работает верно. Значит, для исправления ситуации следует искать лишние вызовы функции. Приложить весь внешний код ему вряд ли удастся к исходному вопросу.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо. @rugabarbo Вы были действительно правы. Я накосячила с вызовом функции. Она вызывалась более одного раза.